# jQuery - counter of filled in form inputs (updated on the fly)

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-calculation

I have basic order form (4 inputs only for testing purposes), i want to count number of inputs (total items) where value is filled in and higher then 0 (basicaly how many products has been ordered, no to confuse with their quantities). When i add products is fine, problems start when I remove items( set them to 0). Could you help me to work it out.

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nitadesign/97tnrepg/33/

And few lines to bring your attention into a right place:

```
function GetOrder(curId){
var order = null;

for(i = 0; i< orders.length; i++){
     if(orders[i].id == curId){
        order = orders[i];
        break;
    }
}

return order;
}

function CalculateTotal(){
var total = 0;
for(i = 0; i< orders.length; i++){
    total = total + orders[i].packTotal;
}
console.log(total);

if(total > 0){
    $("#order_total").html('Total Items:' + i + '<br>' + 'Order Subtotal: ' + total);
    $("#order_total").show();
    $('.submitorder').show();
}
if(total == 0){
    $("#order_total").html('Your shopping basket is empty');
    $("#order_total").show();
    $('.submitorder').hide();
}
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Comment: Please explain what are the _problems_ that start when you remove items.

Comment: for example if update 4 inputs with random value, total items counter will be 4, but then if you update these inputs to 0, total items counter remains 4, is not being deducted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(total > 0){
    var counter = 0;  
    $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
    if($(this).val() != "" && $(this).val() != 0) counter++;
    });
    $("#order_total").html('Total Items:' + counter + '<br>' + 'Order Subtotal: ' + total);
    $("#order_total").show();
    $('.submitorder').show();
}
if(total == 0){
    $("#order_total").html('Your shopping basket is empty');
    $("#order_total").show();
    $('.submitorder').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a jquery selector and loop through it.

```
$("input").change(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    $("input").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() != "" && $(this).val() != 0) counter++;
    });

    $("#order_total").html('Total Items:' + counter + '<br>' + 'Order Subtotal: ' + total);
});
```

Comment: @robbin-roboroads-schepers Thanks a lot. Very nice.